# How to build a recursion for arbitrary lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

To simplify my question I will try give a simple example to make it clearer,if I have this Tree made of lists of lists for instance, the number of lists can be infinitely large e.g.

```
[[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]
```

And I want to cut off its leaves, the nodes that  do not have outgoing edges(empty list), so with the previous input I get this :

```
[[[], []], []]
```

How can I apply the recursion to this type of situations ?

Comment: Can you clarify your example a little more please ? What do you mean by outgoing edges, which elements in your first list does not meet the criteria so you want to eliminate them ?

Comment: I suppose he meant remove all leaves

Comment: @BcK the empty lists are the leaves   [ ]

Comment: @AChampion I apologize, you' re right I meant arbitrary depth, I edited it in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
prune = lambda tree : [prune(branch) for branch in tree if branch != []]

l = [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]
prune(l)
```

Avoiding the use of `lambda` (improving style following comments, and see also [How do I transform this lambda function into def format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201787/how-do-i-transform-this-lambda-function-into-def-format)) the function can be defined as:

```
def prune(tree):
   return [prune(branch) for branch in tree if branch != []]
```

Comment: @BcK this uses recursion, `prune` is being called in the `lambda`. It is trivial to turn this into a `def`ined function.

Comment: @AChampion. Until someone does something evil like messing with the `__globals__` dictionary of your function object so that the name `prune` no longer points back to itself :)

Comment: The only difference between a `lambda` and a def'd function is that the `lambda` hasn't been bound to a variable in the current namespace. This `prune = lambda` business is poor style. How about changing that to a `def prune(tree)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `filter` in recursion:

```
data = [[[], [], [], [], [], []], [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]]
def prune(d):
  return list(map(prune, filter(None, d)))

first, second = map(prune, data))
```

Output:

```
[]
[[[], []], []]
```

Comment: This doesn't always work, e.g. for s=`[[], [], [], [], [], []]` it gives `[[], [], [], [], [], []]` instead of `[]`

Comment: @Fred Please see my recent edit. I consolidated your two sample cases (`[[], [], [], [], [], []]`, `[[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]`) into one list and applied the function to both.