# How do I transform this lambda function into def format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I found this answer to a question here ([How to build a recursion for arbitrary lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200297/how-to-build-a-recursion-for-arbitrary-lists)) but I haven't learnt how to use **lambdas**.

```
prune = lambda tree : [prune(branch) for branch in tree if branch != []]

l = [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]
print prune(l)
```

I checked many websites but I can not seem to manage to transform this into a regular function like:

```
def prune(tree):
    for branch in tree:
        if branch!=[]:
             prune(branch)
    return branch

print prune([[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]])
```

Can someone tell me what are those big square brackets for before prune and at the end?

Comment: `return [prune(branch) for branch in tree if branch != []]`

Comment: Big square brackets are around a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). See also [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)

Comment: BTW, using a `lambda` for a named function is generally considered bad style in Python. They're supposed to be for _anonymous_ functions, so attaching them to a name kind of defeats the purpose. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is slap a `return` on the front.

```
def prune(tree):
    return [prune(branch) for branch in tree if branch != []]
```

If you wanted to decompose the [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)—and there's no real reason to—it'd be:

```
def prune(tree):
    for branch in tree:
        if branch != []:
            yield prune(branch)
```

Or:

```
def prune(tree):
    branches = []

    for branch in tree:
        if branch != []:
            branches.append(prune(branch))

    return branches
```

Answer (score 1):

lambdas are always easily transform-able into a def with a single return statement:

```
f = lambda a: b
```

is always *almost* identical to

```
def f(a):
    return b
```

If you need to do your example without list comprehension:

```
def prune(tree):
    ret = []
    for branch in tree:
        if branch!=[]:
            ret.append(prune(branch))
    return ret
```