# Pass input from one step to other step in Column transformer scikit pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have a pipeline that looks like this:

```
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('categorical_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="constant", fill_value='Unknown')),
    ('encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

fill_na_zero_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('zero_imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value=0))
])

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
       ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = "constant", fill_value=-1, add_indicator=True)),
       ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

preprocess_ppl = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('categorical', categorical_transformer, ['MARITAL_STATUS']),
        ('zero_impute', fill_na_zero_transformer, fill_zero_cols),
        ('numeric', numeric_transformer, num_cols)
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('dropper', drop_cols),
        ('remover',feature_remover),
        ("preprocessor", preprocess_ppl),
        ("estimator", LinearRegression())]
)
```

dropper drops some cols, feature remover also drops based on some logic. In ('numeric', numeric_transformer, num_cols) instead of num_cols I want to get the latest transformed data columns and pass it to 'numeric'.

I.e Lets say that the intermediate data before 'numeric' step is X I want to pass

```
[col for col in num_cols if col in X.columns]
```

instead of num_cols

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; from the docs, the options for the `columns` entry of the `transformers` triples:

> **columns : *str, array-like of str, int, array-like of int, array-like of bool, slice or callable***
>
> [...] A callable is passed the input data `X` and can return any of the above. [...]

So at the most basic, `lambda X: [col for col in num_cols if col in X.columns]` should work.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for answerin. I dnt understand how we can add this. Can you pleas expalin it a bit? :)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to ditch lamda function and use something else? Because lambda is not supported during pickel and I cannot use dill. @Ben Reiniger

Comment: @Obiii Sure, as the docstring says, any callable will do, so define it as a proper function.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But how it this possible? Without lambda X, we dnt have access to X.columns. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50201787/10495893